# Non-blocking connect() and EINTR

Tags: c, sockets, connect, select-function

I am using connect_nonb() from Stevens, UNIX Network programming:

```
int
connect_nonb(int sockfd, const SA *saptr, socklen_t salen, int nsec)
{
    int                     flags, n, error;
    socklen_t               len;
    fd_set                  rset, wset;
    struct timeval  tval;

    flags = Fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    Fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    error = 0;
    if ( (n = connect(sockfd, saptr, salen)) < 0)
            if (errno != EINPROGRESS)
                    return(-1);

    /* Do whatever we want while the connect is taking place. */

    if (n == 0)
            goto done;      /* connect completed immediately */

    FD_ZERO(&rset);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &rset);
    wset = rset;
    tval.tv_sec = nsec;
    tval.tv_usec = 0;

    if ( (n = Select(sockfd+1, &rset, &wset, NULL,
                                     nsec ? &tval : NULL)) == 0) {
            close(sockfd);          /* timeout */
            errno = ETIMEDOUT;
            return(-1);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rset) || FD_ISSET(sockfd, &wset)) {
            len = sizeof(error);
            if (getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len) < 0)
                    return(-1);                     /* Solaris pending error */
    } else
            err_quit("select error: sockfd not set");

done:
    Fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags);  /* restore file status flags */

    if (error) {
            close(sockfd);          /* just in case */
            errno = error;
            return(-1);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

This function allows a custom timeout of connect(). If, whilst blocking in select() waiting for the connect to succeed, a signal is received, select() exits with -1 (EINTR). At this point the select() timeout has not expired, the connect has not succeeded (i.e. the target host could be disconnected) but the subsequent getsockopt() does not return an error.

Should getsockopt() return an error or should the Stevens code check the return code (and errno) of select()?

Currently when connecting to a non-existent host and a signal interrupts select() this function returns success incorrectly.

Comment: It most certainly should check the return code of `select`. Not doing that is, in my mind, quite a big oversight.

Comment: Select has a capital S in your example, which means he's wrapped it. What's in the wrapped version of select? I would expect him to catch and handle EINTR there, that's what I'd do...

Comment: Joe, I thought that too but Select() just adds error printing. http://pastebin.com/Eua4vdZE

Comment: That does seem strange then, it's not caught in the errata for the book is it?..

Comment: It appears it's "sort of" caught in the errata - http://www.kohala.com/start/typos.unpv12e.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `Select()` is. I assume it's some kind of thin wrapper around `select()`.

In most applications, whenever `select()` fails with `EINTR`, you should silently loop and call `select()` again, possibly after recalculating the timeout to account for the fact that some time has elapsed in the prior call to `select()`.

This case is no exception. `select()` should be in a loop.